# nodejs - simple-xmpp connection required every time to call xmpp methods?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

We want to make sure before implementation of `nodejs` - `simple-xmpp` module for chat with `ejabberd` server.

We're Using below Technologies to create web chat:

- `Nodejs` with `expressjs` web framework
- `nodejs` - `simple-xmpp` module (Used to connect, chat, get roster, get chat history, chat state etc with ejabberd server!) - https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-xmpp
- WebSocket - socket IO - http://socket.io/
- ejabberd Server - https://www.ejabberd.im/

Our main question is that while using `simple-xmpp` module methods every time  we need to use `xmpp.connect();` with their params how to prevent that ?

Is there any way to make it `xmpp` connection globally or `xmpp` connect only one time when user logged-In into our application and we can use other `xmpp` method using by `xmpp` global connection etc ?

Please let us know how to keep alive `xmpp` existing connection ?

Comment: did you find a solution? Please share.